# Connecting to sybase ase with specific charset from a software

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I need to connect a Sybase ASE database with a specific charset. I have data with a charset that cannot be read properly by the default charset of Sybase ASE. I know how to connect with "isqln -J" but what I need is a little more complicated.
I have software that connects itself to an ASE database but it doesn't ask for a charset while establishing the connection, so it connects with the default charset.

What I want to ask is, are any of these options possible;

- Can I change the default charset of Sybase ASE (not the database charset - I tried changing it, didn't work)
- Can I track the connection so just before login (with login trigger etc.) I intercept the connection and change it to my needs (adding "-J" parameter maybe)

I tried changing the database's charset, system's charset, OEM charset, etc. none of these seem to work. The third-party software still connects the database with the default charset, so it cannot read the values with special characters properly

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted -- Sybase ASE can only work fine when server/client's charset are same or compatible -- eg. when using iso_1 on server and client must be iso_1 too, or Server is cp936 and client is cp936 or the subset of cp936-- gb2312... Otherwise on client, you can only get illegal characters like space or square or XXX...
So here's the answer -- please check your ASE server's charset --
sp_helpsort
I don't know what client software you are using, but most general sybase client will call OS's Language settings to set as client's default charset.    Then set it on your client's charset -- on linux/unix you can set it with LC_ALL or LANG, on windows, you can set it in Windows Unicode settings.
HTH